# Calculating MIDI Clock - PPQN duration

Tags: c++, midi

Every reference I can find says you send a MIDI Clock 'pulse' every
x = 60,000,000 * (BPM * PPQN) microseconds.

But the time signature denominator determines the length of a quarter note, and there's no mention of that in the formula.  Since PPQN is based on quarter notes, I'm really confused as to why it's not.

Can anyone help clear up my confusion?

Answer (score 0):

That formula is wrong.

There are 24 clocks per quarter note. One beat is a quarter note, so the BPM value specifies quarter notes per minute. One minute has 60,000,000 microseconds.

So the number of microseconds between two MIDI clocks is 60,000,000 / (24 × BPM).